# find all Possible Decoding of given digit sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Here's the problem:

Assume that the value of a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ... , z = 26. You are given a numeric string S. Write a program to return the list of all possible codes that can be generated from the given string.

So, `1123` will produce the following output:

> aabc kbc alc aaw kw

So the way I'm approaching is this:

first map each alphabet to number, for e.g, `"1":"a", "2":"b"...` and so on.

Then recursively divide the problem:
`f("123") = {alphabetMap("1")+ f("23"), alphabetMap("12") + f("3")}`

So I draw the recursive tree with this approach and able to find the solution.

But somewhere there seems to be a problem when I implement the same.

```js
var alphabetMap = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= 26; i++){
    alphabetMap[i] = String.fromCharCode(96 + i);
}
//Gives {"1": "a", "2": "b",........."26": "z"}

var res = [];
function encrypt(str, i = 0, newStr = ""){
    if(i >= str.length){
        res.push(newStr);
        return;
    }

    encrypt(str, i + 1, newStr + (alphabetMap[str[i]] || ''));
    encrypt(str, i + 2, newStr + (alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]] || ''));
}

encrypt("1123");
console.log(res)
```

Another issue I wanted to understand with this problem is how to intuitively think when there would be just one index needed to find all combination and when we'd need more.

For e.g, see this

[Find all combinations of interleaving two strings. Where am I making mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77615183/find-all-combinations-of-interleaving-two-strings-where-am-i-making-mistake)

This problem is similar and the breakdown of the problem is similar too as with each step the problem is going to be divided into two. But we need two indices because we need two set of strings. Same argument can be applied here but here I think just once index suffices.

Appreciate insight on this.

Comment: "somewhere there seems to be a problem" suggests no effort at trying even confirm that there is a problem, much less identifying what it is or try to fix it.

Comment: What I meant is I'm able to draw the recursive tree with pen and paper and arrive at the solution. But in my implementation something is going wrong.

Comment: So trace the execution of your program to see where it differs from your pen/paper solution.

Comment: @ABGR.  How do you know something is going wrong with your implementation?

Comment: I didn't understand the assignment completely: "possible codes" - does this mean you get something like `"1"` and the result is `["a"]`, so a possible code consists only of letters? Could you add some more examples for (simple) inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: @ScottHunter You're right. But when the program goes wrong, self doubts start creeping in.. *is my approach even right* or *am i missing something in the base case* mind goes into too many directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea with recursion is fine, and yes, this only needs one index (since there is only one string to iterate). At each stage your function will try the two possibilities. But that is where you have a bug: before looking into the case where you take *two* digits, you should ensure that the string still has that many characters available.

In that case `+ str[i + 1]` will be undefined, and although you have provision for that case with `|| ''` this means you make the recursive call with `newStr` itself (nothing appended to it), while still skipping the last character at `i`. In your example this means you output first `aabc` (correct), but then also `aab`, skipping the input "3" because there was no second character following it.

The fix is to replace this:

```
encrypt(str, i + 2, newStr + (alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]] || ''));
```

with this:

```
if (i + 2 <= str.length && alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]]){
    encrypt(str, i + 2, newStr + alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]]);
}
```

...so that you only apply the recursion when there are at least two digits, and that digit pair has a mapping. Now it will output the correct result. It is true you could rely on the `undefined` behaviour and leave out the length check, but the check on the existence of the mapping is a requirement for going into recursion. The call should not be made otherwise.

#### Other remarks

- Don't use a global variable to collect the results. This is not good and would give you wrong results when you call the function multiple times from the main program.
- I would not pass the partial code (`newStr`) as an argument to the recursive call. It seems more elegant to have the recursive call return the possible codes for the substring it received, and let the caller do the job of prefixing those with the current letter. That way it works from the inside-out (post order processing)
- Passing the start index is fine, but JavaScript is quite efficient with slicing strings (using string kerning), so you could just pass the string slice instead of the original string. This reduces the number of arguments to just one.
- Instead of building the result in such a way that the function *returns* the list of codes (which is way better than populating a global variable), you could also *yield* the codes using a generator.
- You don't really need the alphabet map, as it is straightforward to do the decoding directly with `String.fromCharCode`.

Here is how that would turn out:

```js
function* encryptIter(str) {
    if (!str) return yield "";
    for (let len = 1; len <= 2; len++) {
        const code = String.fromCharCode(96 + +str.slice(0, len));
        if (str.length >= len && code <= "z") {
            for (const result of encrypt(str.slice(len))) {
                // Prefix the current code to the results for the shorter string
                yield code + result;
            }
        }
    }
}

const encrypt = (str) => [...encryptIter(str)];

const res = encrypt("1123");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you. That indeed seemed to be the issue.
But the way, *I thought* I was guarding that was with this:
` newStr + (alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]] || '')` i.e if the character is undefined, it would be `''` So Could you please elaborate how that was the issue. Second, can you please address the second part as well comparing the linked question?

Comment: I added more detail to the bug description. The linked question needs two indices, because there are two separate strings involved which need to have their own "current" index. As you have just one input string, and the problem just needs one current index (with potentially looking at the successor), you only need one index (or slicing).

Comment: Thank you. This is just great. Also, by adding this condition `&& alphabetMap[str[i] + str[i + 1]]` you also took into account a case which I was missing, say, there's still a digit at `i+1` but shouldn't go into recursion because it's exceeds `26`, say, `3543` *(35 exceeding 26)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with generators. I find `yield` expressions allow me to think about the program from a higher level. Another advantage is the generator is pauseable/cancelable so that you do not need to generate the entire result set if it's not needed.

```js
const alphabet = Array.from(
  Array(26),
  (value, index) => String.fromCharCode(96 + index),
)

function *decode(s) {
  if (s == "")
    yield ""
  
  if (s.length >= 1)
    for (const plain of decode(s.slice(1)))
      yield *combine(s.slice(0, 1), plain)

  if (s.length >= 2)
    for (const plain of decode(s.slice(2)))
      yield *combine(s.slice(0, 2), plain)
}

function *combine(s, plain) {
  if (s in alphabet)
    yield alphabet[s] + plain
}

for (const res of decode("1123"))
  console.log(res)
```

```
aabc
aaw
alc
kbc
kw
```

This code is nicely arranged to handle errors. Update the `combine` function to -

```js
function *combine(s, plain) {
  if (s in alphabet)
    yield alphabet[s] + plain
  else
    yield `[ERROR: ${s}]` + plain // ✅
}
```

Now when the input is invalid -

```js
for (const res of decode("112a3"))
  console.log(res)
```

```
aab[ERROR: a]c
aab[ERROR: a3]
aa[ERROR: 2a]c
al[ERROR: a]c
al[ERROR: a3]
kb[ERROR: a]c
kb[ERROR: a3]
k[ERROR: 2a]c
```

Comment: Thank you. This is another way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic non-recursive approach (basically, BFS the tree instead of DFS).

The function expects a `Map` `prefix => code` and a source string. Prefixes and codes can be whatever, not necessary digits or letters.

```js
const prefixes = new Map([
    ['1', 'a'],
    ['2', 'b'],
    ['3', 'c'],
    ['4', 'd'],
    ['5', 'e'],
    ['6', 'f'],
    ['7', 'g'],
    ['8', 'h'],
    ['9', 'i'],
    ['10', 'j'],
    ['11', 'k'],
    ['12', 'l'],
    ['13', 'm'],
    ['14', 'n'],
    ['15', 'o'],
    ['16', 'p'],
    ['17', 'q'],
    ['18', 'r'],
    ['19', 's'],
    ['20', 't'],
    ['21', 'u'],
    ['22', 'v'],
    ['23', 'w'],
    ['24', 'x'],
    ['25', 'y'],
    ['26', 'z'],
])

function encode(prefixes, str) {
    let res = [],
        queue = [['', str]]

    while (queue.length > 0) {
        let [encoded, notEncoded] = queue.shift()
        if (notEncoded === '')
            res.push(encoded)
        else {
            for (let [pfx, code] of prefixes.entries()) {
                if (notEncoded.indexOf(pfx) === 0) {
                    queue.push([encoded + code, notEncoded.slice(pfx.length)])
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}

console.log(...encode(prefixes, '1123'))
```

Comment: Great approach. Thank you.